# get current location in first run

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I have an app that uses location services but when I request for current location and after user allowed permission, app could not find location.
for user to find it's location must close and re-open the app till find correct position.
here's my code :

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.getCurrentLocation();
}
getCurrentLocation = () => {
    const locationConfig = {
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        this.iGetLocation,
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        locationConfig
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in your position callback: `this.iGetPosition`. Try to use a callback function, like below.
This is working for me(check the `getCurrentPosition` function):

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.requestAccess();
 }
 requestAccess = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Location permission',
          'message': 'App needs access to your location ' +
                     'so we can show your location.'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            this.setState({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              error: null,
            });
          },
          (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
        );

      } else {
        console.log("Location permission denied")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }
```